# Seaborn. TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm studying 'seaborn'

In the first step drawing 'regplot', I have a problem

below the coding gives me an Error, `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`

I don't understand that error.

That thing is my questions

1. dtype(age) & dtype(float) are all float
   but, why the error say int?
2. How should I do that to resolve the problem?

give me advice, please. Thank you in advance!!

```
enter code here

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic',dtype=np.int32)

sns.set_style('darkgrid')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

sns.regplot(x='age',y='fare', data=titanic, ax=ax1)

sns.regplot(x='age',y='fare', data=titanic, ax=ax2, fit_reg=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `dtype=np.int64` instead of `np.int32` in the line where you load the dataset? What happens when you do?

Comment: You shouldn't force `dtype` to `np.int32` since some data in [*titanic.csv*](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/titanic.csv) is not integer. After removing that restrict, your code works fine with seaborn 0.10.1.

Comment: i tried to upgrade seaborn version. after then the coding was operated well (i removed np.int32 also)
Thank you!!!